# Store reference to a variable with a primitive value

Tags: javascript

I would like to write a function with a signature like

```
broadcast(centerPiece.rotation.y);
```

which stores the passed variable and publishes the value at the variable on all animation frames there after.

The issue is that I'm mostly interested in broadcasting primitive values, meaning the function above grabs the primitive value at the moment of the function call and keeps broadcasting that fixed value.

Currently I'm using this workaround

```
broadcast = function(obj,prop){
  doBusinessLogicWith(obj[prop])
}
```

giving me a rather ugly signature in my code looking like

```
broadcast(centerPiece.rotation,'y');
```

This currently works because universally I will only need to broadcast properties on objects, but ... it's a little ugly. **Do I have better options for tracking a variable storying a primitive value?**

Comment: No. Only properties can be used as references.

Answer (score 1):

One *slightly less ugly* option might be to pass in a reference to a function that gets the current value.  Something like:

```
broadcast = function(getValue){
  var curVal = getValue();
  doBusinessLogicWith(curVal);
}
```

Then call it with:

```
broadcast(function ()
{
   return centerPiece.rotation.y;
});
```